# How do I creat a TaskGroup in VSTS, link to a deliverable and make this into a template?

Tags: azure-devops

Looks like everything is working except the "linking to parent deliverable" portion. Any ideas?

Comment: what did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom build template that includes task group.

1. Create a build definition
2. Add a task group to build definition
3. Save build definition
4. Go to build definitions list page (Click Builds tab)
5. Hover mouse to that build definition
6. Click … Save as a template

[image]

Then, you can create a new build definition with this custom template and the related task group has already added.